# Jquery Mobile Back Button Redirect to Particular page

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I want to call function **callsomefunction();** only if **rdFlag=='N'** is set, but in my case , the function is triggered everytime when i click back button,i think its due to **$(document)** used. Is there any other solution for this method.

My code below:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "index.php?messageid="+messageid,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
              success: function(data){
                $('.ui-loader').css('display', 'none');
                $('#addmodal1 #content').html('');  
                $('#addmodal1 #content').html(data);
                $("#addmodal1 #content").trigger("create"); 
                $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#addmodal1");

                **if(rdFlag=='N') {**
                    alert(rdFlag);
                    **$(document).on('click', '[data-rel=back]' , function(event) { 
                        alert('in');
                        callsomefunction();
                    });**
                }
            }   
        });
```

Comment: where do you  rdFlag variable gets updated?

Comment: @Muthu rdFlag is set as parameter for this function, inside which this ajax call is invoked. And i have checked rdFlag is returning correctly.

Comment: Is this part if(rdFlag=='N') executing correctly?

Comment: @Muthu yeah its working correctly. But the thing is the $(document) function is triggering where ever i click back button.

Comment: Try to add a class $(document).on('click', '.something',... it may help to solve your issues.

Comment: @Muthu Thanks :-) it worked. Can you submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this following code

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-rel=back]' , function(event)
```

with this

```
$(document).on('click', '.classname' , function(event)
```